# Mousewheel not working after starting

Tags: mouse

I installed elementary OS some time ago and I must say I really like the 'flow' of it. Although I have unfortunately some technical issues. One of them is the mouse.

My Problem: When I start the PC the mousewheel does not work. I have to unplug it and reinsert it. Then everything works fine.

The mouxe is the X7 Spider. lsusb after reinserting it:

```
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 09da:9090 A4Tech Co., Ltd. XL-730K / XL-750BK / XL-755BK Mice
```

dmesg | grep mouse

```
[    1.229382] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
```

So far I have no idea what else I could post to analyze this issue further.

You have any hints for me to look at this issue besides unplugging it or how to solve it?

Thanks,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time I found how to solve that problem. Someone else had a similar one. Here is the link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/213712/how-can-i-change-mouse-keymapping